# SUM of Product of 2 Columns + the Product of another two columns in Entity Framework Navigation Properties

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6, linq-to-entities

I am trying to write a statement to get the sum of the product two fields in Entity Framework.

Given the following structure:

```
public class Order
{
    public int OrderNUmber {get; set;}
    public virtual List<Orderline> OrderLines {get; set;}
    public virtual List<ServiceLine> ServiceLines {get; set;}
    public string someproperty {get; set;}
}

public class OrderLine
{
    public string productname {get; set;}
    public int quantity {get; set;}
    public decimal price {get; set;}
}

public class ServiceLine
{
    public string servicename {get; set;}
    public int quantity {get; set;}
    public decimal rate {get; set;}
}
```

I am trying to return the total order value in one query:

```
var GrandTotal = Orders.Where(q => q.someproperty == "somecondition")
                 .Sum(order =>
                           order.OrderLines.Sum(line => line.quantity * line.price) 
                         + order.ServiceLines.Sum(sl =>sl.quantity * sl.rate));
```

However this version does dot get the correct total. The number is WAY less than expected.

Comment: EF's query is getting nulls due to the way they are summing up these lines.

Answer (score 0):

So the problem here was that EF was getting a null value for any order that didn't have any ServiceLines, instead of adding zero.

Both of these options work:

```
 .Sum(
                order =>
                       order.OrderLines.Select(n => new{n.quantity, n.price}).DefaultIfEmpty(new {quantity = 0, price = decimal.Zero}).Sum(line => line.quantity * line.price) + order.ServiceLines.Select(n => new{n.quantity, n.rate}).DefaultIfEmpty(new {quantity = 0, rate = decimal.Zero}).Sum(acl =>acl.quantity * acl.rate) 
                );
```

AND

```
.Sum(
                order =>
                    order.OrderLines.Select(lines => new { LineTotal = lines.quantity * lines.price }).DefaultIfEmpty(new { LineTotal = Decimal.Zero }).Sum(x => x.LineTotal) + order.ServiceLines.Select(acl => new { AclTotal = acl.quantity * acl.rate }).DefaultIfEmpty(new { AclTotal = Decimal.Zero }).Sum(x => x.AclTotal)
            );
```

It is necessary to tell EF the DefaultIfEmpty value of the anonymous object, otherwise it will screw up the addition with nulls. So EF would get OrderLineTotal (value) + ServiceLineTotal (NULL) = NULL.